# How do I make a drop down menu in a table that does an action i.e. redirect to a page based on the entry in that row (HTML, PHP)

Tags: php, html

What I'm doing right now is making a student design system. The user first lands on a page that shows all the entries in the database in an html table. There's a Add New Student button above the table and what I'm trying to do now is have a drop down menu for each entry in a separate column at the end of each row. For example

John Smith 007 (drop down menu here that gives options to edit/delete an entry etc)

Alex Adams 002 (drop down menu here that gives options to edit/delete an entry etc)

I've got the layout etc done but the problem right now is that the dropdown menu doesn't identify which row its in. What I mean is if I select Edit from the drop down menu in John's row, it should automatically go to a page that edits John but right now that doesn't happen since the drop down menu doesn't have it saved anywhere that its in John's row.

How do I make the drop down menu so that if I select delete from the drop down menu in Alex's row, it just deletes Alex.

EDIT: Here's some code that I've written so far. This is just the front page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="addstudent.html" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Add New Student" />
        </form>



        <table border="2">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th> 
          <th>Student ID</th>
          <th>Date of Birth</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 

        <?php
        $servername="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $databasee="myStudents";

        $conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $databasee);
        if(!$conn){
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }


        $sql =" SELECT * FROM studentsTable ";

        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['firstname'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['lastname'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['studentid'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['dob'] ?></td>
            <td>
                <form action="dropSwitch.php" method="post">
                <select name="option">
                    <option value="Edit">Edit</option>
                    <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Go" />
            </form>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post some code what you have right now?

Comment: are you using id for select ? and handling by id attribute ?

Comment: what did you try so far ? providing the code you wrote will help.

Comment: You could add an `<input type="hidden">` with the `studentid` value, so that your dropSwitch script knows which student is being edited/deleted

Comment: I've updated with the code. @rickdenhaan how would I incorporate that into the code? The drop down menu is automatically created with each entry

Answer (score 0):

You should make the Dropdown Tabs for Delete or Edit an `<a>`
 Tag and give the `href` a dynamic route depending on the user fetched, if you set up the Routing correct you could then simply grab an UserID or the Name(But must be unique) from the URL and fetch data for this User on your Edit Page and edit him there.

Any more Questions just comment.

Edit for Question 1:

```
 <form action="dropSwitch.php" method="post">
            <select name="option">
                <option value="Edit">Edit</option>
                <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
            </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
```

Turn this into:

```
            <select name="option">
                <option value="Edit"><a href="<?..../$studentid?>Edit</a></option>
               <option value="Delete"><a href="<?..../$studentid?>Delete</a></option>
            </select>
```

Comment: How would I send the information in that row to the next page using just the drop down menu? As you can see in the code, the drop down is created automatically depending on the number of entries and none of them are linked to the information in that row

Comment: @Shahmeer I editet my Post, do you Need the dropSwitch.php? And what does it?

Comment: No I don't need it, I had it there for redirecting to the right page but it doesn't work since the drop down didn't know which row it was in.

As for your code, are you adding the user ID in the URL? Sorry I don't exactly get whats happening there.

Comment: @Shahmeer No Problem. Yes basicly you add the in your case studentid into the url which will be a different one in each row depending on the row itself. Then you get a new page which has the Studentid that wants to get editet in the URL so you just have to read it out of the url and then you can do whatever you want with that dataste in the next page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden `<input>` to your form for each student:

```
<td>
    <form action="dropSwitch.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="studentid" value="<?php echo $row['studentid'] ?>" />
        <select name="option">
            <option value="Edit">Edit</option>
            <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
</td>
```

Then, from within `dropSwitch.php`, you can access `$_POST['studentid']` to find out which student needs to be edited or deleted.